# ASP.NET MVC 5 Web Application Slow Performance

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, iis-7, asp.net-mvc-routing, windows-server-2012

I am working on a new ASP.NET MVC Web application and I see that all pages take about 12-15 seconds to load irrespective of what is in the controller or view. I have pages that take about 8 secs with no code in controller other than return View() and view page with just the page name in the html.

I ran the SQL Profiler and the response is very fast so it seems like the MVC routing or something is taking up all the time. So far I have tried below approaches:

1. Removed all view engines from global.asax and used only the Razor View Engine
2. Enabled Bundling and Minification for css and js
3. Enabled compression for static and dynamic content under IIS 7
4. I deployed the Release Build on our dev server but still same performance

Please let me know what could be the reason behind the slow performance of the MVC application.

On a different note, for an enterprise web application with about 150-250 users browsing at the same time, what would be the best server configuration I should have like CPU, Processor, RAM etc.

Comment: It would be useful to measure the actual Request duration (e.g., use Chrome's Network profiler in Developer Utils or a Tool called Fiddler), so first you focus on the pure server side performance and ignore possible scripting delays. At a later stage, you could use Microsofts Application Insights tools, they help finding bottlenecks

Comment: Do you see the same performance issue if you create a brand new default template app with nothing in it?  If not, then you know it was code that's been added since.

Comment: The problem really is with loading the URL. When I click on any link in the site to navigate to a different URL, the browser will take 5-6 seconds just to update the URL in browser address bar and after that it takes about 1-3 seconds to load the page. So I believe that most of the time is wasted in finding the URL. Can anyone point out why is it taking the time to find the URL when the path is already available in the "href" attribute.

Answer (score -1):

I faced similar issue and found our the culprit. It is 'NativeCode' checkbox under **Right click on Project Properties->Web->Debugger section**. This causes a very slow loading time due to symbols loaded from GAC,GAC64 etc.

After **unchecking the NativeCode** check box, the site loads very fast.
Please give it a try.

[image]